# Hitting a break wall with SVG

Tags: svg

Why a light colored rectangle background showed up on the area behind xlink every time it is touched or clicked?

Here is my SVG code:

```
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 147.86 258.44" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g class="bglyr" fill="none" transform="translate(-30.575,-20.926)">
<a xlink:href="https://google.com">
<path id="link1" fill="none" onmouseover="change(this)" onmouseout="unchange(this)" d="m104.43 242.44 11.742 6.1664 57.094 29.884-137.62 0.0617z" />                           
<a />
</g>
</svg>
```

JavaScript:

```
function change(item) {
    item.style.fill = "#42d46b";
    item.style.opacity = "1.0";
}
function unchange(item) {
    item.style.fill = "none";
    item.style.opacity = "0.0";
}
```

Comment: "a light colored rectangle background" do not appear when clicked, and the `touch` and `untouch` functions aren't called either because you forgot to add your css. Also you have a typo at closing the `a`

Comment: enxaneta: why touch and untouch functions need css? they are functions written in JavaScript? a typo at closing the a? i am sorry, i don't understand?

Comment: `<a />` should be `</a>`

Comment: What "light colored rectangle" are you referring to?
There is nothing in your code that looks like that.  Also you refer to "every time it is touched or clicked". But your code uses `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`, not `onclick` or `ontouch`.  Please update your question with a better explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case your question is actually about why your example code doesn't work, then I can explain that for you.

Mouse events won't be triggered if your `<path>` has nothing to hover over. When the `fill` is `"none"` or the `opacity` is `0`. No mouse events will be triggered.  To fix this, use `fill="transparent"` instead.  This behaves the same way, but **is** detected as if it was any other non-transparent fill colour.

```js
function change(item) {
    item.style.fill = "#42d46b";
}
function unchange(item) {
    item.style.fill = "transparent";
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 147.86 258.44" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<g class="bglyr" fill="none" transform="translate(-30.575,-20.926)">
<a xlink:href="https://google.com">
<path id="link1" fill="transparent" onmouseover="change(this)" onmouseout="unchange(this)" d="m104.43 242.44 11.742 6.1664 57.094 29.884-137.62 0.0617z" />                           
</a>
</g>
</svg>
```